# pre-built django project gives error on migrate

Tags: django, postgresql, manage.py, django-manage.py

I have a pre-built django project, and need to run it on ubuntu 18. Went through & installed all prerequisites, using postgresql as db engine. created a db for project and added user with required privilleges & then updated those settings into `settings.py` file

then I ran following commands to ready migrations & implement it.

```
# python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

&

```
# python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 77, in handle
    connection.prepare_database()
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 26, in prepare_database
    cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis")
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/hsn/env_banax_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

Do any of you have any idea how to fix it?? The django server is running, but I get this page instead, I guess there's something related with db connectivity.
Screenshot of page showing right now is attached.

[image]

Comment: No, that screenshot has nothing to do with connectivity. It tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so what to look for as a sysadmin?

Comment: try adding postgis extension in your database on your own with the superuser of postgres

Comment: @Sanip I'm getting errors while creating superuser as well.

Comment: Do you mean about django superuser or postgres superuser?

Comment: @Sanip creating with manage.py

Comment: Check my answer below. The superuser i was referring to was postgres superuser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is: **create the `postgis extension` in your database using the `postgres superuser`**.

- Log in to the postgres shell by using the superuser username(the one that you provided while installing postgresql):

  sudo -i -u < superuser_username > psql
- Connect to your database:

  \connect < database_name >
- Create the postgis extension as:

  create extension postgis;

You can learn about the user privileges [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/testing/#obtaining-sufficient-privileges) if you face problems in privileges while creating the extension.

Comment: but am still getting same page not found, and admin panel doesn't load either. Even though tables of my db show data in terminal

Comment: Are you sure you have a `urlconf` for '/' in your app?

Comment: Thanks, for steps wise explanation. Can you help me Shapefile map use in website.